# Get different SRIDs of geometry column in a table

Tags: postgis, srid

It is possible that a geometry column in a table of PostGIS has different SRIDs. I've used Find_SRID to get the SRID of this column but seems it only returns one value for SRID which is the first row. What is the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If column in your table has explicitly defined geometry type and srid, like:

```
CREATE TABLE geom_table (id serial, geom geometry(point,3857);
```

Your database will not allow to place there any other geometries than point in srid 3857... but you can also define table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE geom_table (id serial, geom geometry);
```

Than you can store there different geometries in different srids.
You can use [ST_GeometryType](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html) and [ST_SRID](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SRID.html) to find out what is in this column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST_SRID(geom) FROM table;

SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(geom) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Find_SRID` function will only return the SRID specified for this column. Only one value is defined so it returns only one row (see https://postgis.net/docs/Find_SRID.html).

If you want to get the SRID for every single geometry in your table try:

```
select st_srid(yourgeom) from yourtable;
```

or to get all the used srids only once:

```
select distinct st_srid(yourgeom) from yourtable;
```

But I think if you defined some SRID for your geometry column, PostGIS will only accept geometries with this SRID. So the last query will only return one SRID value.